# How to login to Application on MAC by python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new with python and started to learn it.I'm making a script which opens Application and then i want to pass my username/passwd to login in it.

How i can convert it to script? I can open application via os.system and then it gives me App username/passwd box and it works? How i can cover username/passwd from script?

Is there any module for that? I looked on selenium which does only supports webdrivers.

When i open app , it asks for username/passwd and then once i click on login button it works.

Comment: Have you tried pyautogui module?

Comment: Mac apps generally support scripting so there is less need for silly GUI automation.

Comment: nah, i did not try pyautogui, trying to find good example for this to understand.

Comment: basically, this is vpn app , i can not find its script mode or a way to do it